# placeholder attribute is invalid when check it in browser

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I assign values to placeholder within every tag like:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-1 control-label">FirstName</label>
    <div class="col-sm-11">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" value= {{ form.first_name.value }} name="first_name" placeholder="first_name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lastname" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Lastname</label>
    <div class="col-sm-11">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="last_name" value= {{ form.first_name.value }} placeholder="last_name">
    </div>
  </div>
```

However, when I check it on browser, it displays None.

[image]

How to solve such a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the value in string format as shown below:

```
value="{% if form.first_name.value %}{{ form.first_name.value }}{%else%}{%endif%}"
```

This will fix the issue because if **value** attribute's value is empty then only **placeholder** attribute's value comes into picture!

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is actually exactly what you wrote. `form.first_name.value` is `None` if not set on the form, so it sets `value="None"` and lo, that is what the form dutifully displays in preference to the placeholder.

You need to get a '' for your default value if a `field.value` is `None`. One way would be an explicit check using `{% if form.first_name.value %} {{ form.first_name.value }} {% endif %}`. More concisely, `{{ form.first_name.value|default_if_none:"" }}` using a template filter.